# Drupal 8 Twig Page Fields

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

So I'm just getting started with Drupal and Drupal 8 and have a hard time understanding accessing twig content. Ideally what I would like to do is require some fields using the structured content.

When a type of structured content is used I would like to load a specific twig template and access the fields by machine readable name. This will allow me to setup template types with specific requirements for content.

I'm struggling with 2 parts and maybe what I want to do isn't possible in drupal. The first part how do I assign a page template based on structured content type?

The second issue is how do print out specific fields. I'm able to print all fields using {{page.content}} but {{page.content.field_name}} prints nothing. I'm very confused how to proceed forward. I know I can use modules and assign them to sections but for structured data types this won't allow for rigid enforcement of data collection like structured content. Some of this content flows outside a single content area so I'd really like to do it in a main layout file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. For defining page template based on content type:
   You can have:

   - page--front.html.twig - For front page
   - page--user.html.twig - For user page
   - page--youtube_videos.html.twig - For content type (here it is: youtube_videos)
2. For print content fields, you need to goto node.html.twig

   - For image field: {{ content.field_image }}
   - For title: {{ label }}
   - Tag field: {{ content.field_tags }}